# Probability that at least one of the first $k$ right-to-left maxima of $\{1, ..., n+m\}$ contains a number from $\{n+1, ..., n+m\}$

Tags: co.combinatorics, pr.probability, sequences-and-series

Given a permutation $\sigma$ on $[n]=\{1, ..., n\}$, we say an element $i$ is a right-to-left maximum if $\sigma(i)=\max(\sigma(1), ..., \sigma(i))$.

Suppose we sample a random permutation from $\{1, ..., n+m\}$ for $n\geq k$ and $m\geq 1$, what is the probability that at least one of the first $k$ right-to-left maxima contains a number from $\{n+1, ..., n+m\}$ in a random permutation?

**Attempt:**

The number of permutations with $i$ right-to-left maxima of $[p]$ is known to be equal to ${p \brack i}$, the (unsigned) Stirling number of the first kind. So one can form such permutation by guessing the location $1\leq \ell \leq n+1$ in $\sigma$ of the first element from $\{n+1, ..., n+m\}$, then we choose $\ell-1$ values from $\{1, ..., n\}$ to put in locations $1, ..., \ell-1$, and guess how many right-to-left maxima they have $0\leq t\leq k-1$, then put the remaining $n+m-\ell$ elements after index $\ell$ and permute them. This gives a total number of permutations of

$$\sum_{\ell=1}^{n+1} \sum_{t=0}^{k-1}  m\cdot {n \choose \ell-1} \cdot {\ell-1 \brack t}\cdot (n+m-\ell)!$$

Dividing by $(n+m)!$ gives the result.

**Question:**

Is there a way to simplify this sum? Or derive the answer some other way directly? I tried on Mathematica with no luck.

Comment: Do you have a reason to suspect a particularly simple answer to this problem?

Comment: @SamHopkins I don't have any reason to know that a simple answer exists or doesn't exist. The only *hint* at this is the identity $\sum_{p=k}^n {n \brack p}{p \choose k} = {n+1 \brack k+1}$. I suspect maybe one summation might be able to be cancelled (which would help a lot).

Answer (score 4):

The given expression represents the coefficient of $x^{k-1}$ in
$$(-1)^n\cdot m!\cdot (-x-m)_n\cdot (1-x)^{-1},$$
where $(\cdot)_{\cdot}$ is [falling factorial](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Falling_and_rising_factorials).